# How to store a array element in local storage

Tags: json, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3, local-storage

I'm new to ionic 3. i need to store a array element in local storage.

> I tried this code but it only storing the array. Not an **array element**

This is my code:

```
signin() {
    this.showLoader();
    console.log(this.loginData);
    this.authService.login(this.loginData).then((result) => {
      this.loading.dismiss();
      this.data = result;
      console.log('Result:'+JSON.stringify(result));
      localStorage.setItem('token', JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.data))._body.access_token);
       console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.data))._body.access_token);
      this.navCtrl.setRoot(DashboardPage);
```

and this is an result value

```
Result:{"_body":"{\"access_token\":\"J0ErN5qf4btTJaB27FLMNLTrhwBxZMTCBAxc4m25\",\"token_type\":\"Bearer\",\"expires_in\":3600,\"refresh_token\":\"OMVvOXHgsfKwWtHyYwjlzsO5Jxb44H0Oi9lf7Pk6\"}",
```

> In short, i need to store the access_token in **local storage**. please suggest some method.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi, have you tried to store "result" in local storage directly without converting it in JSON format?

Comment: yeah, i tried but that shows   "token= undefined"

Comment: What do you get if you console.log `result._body.access_token`?  If you just need to store the access token, it seems like you could just grab that element off the `result` object without messing with parse/stringify?

Comment: What is “array element” in your case? I am confused a bit. Your Result seems to me a json.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is how are you storing the value in the localStorage, the correct implementation would be:

**Save to localStorage:**

```
localStorage.setItem('token', JSON.stringify(this.data._body.access_token));
```

**Get from localStorage:**

```
JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('token'));
```